# "pythonw.exe entry point not found" when running spyder in an environment

Tags: python, virtualenv, spyder

Error Notification:

> The proceduce entry point
> ?PyWinObject_AsWriteBuffer@@YAHPEAU_object@@PEAPEAXPEAKH@Z could not
> be located in the dynamic link library
> C:\Users\Admin\anaconda3:ibrary\bin\pythoncom38.dll

I was using `virtualenv` to create an environment for my Python project instead of using "anaconda navigator" because it takes me too long to switch and run spyder in it. So I installed spyder inside my environment with `pip install spyder` and ran spyder via my env prompt. The error message appears and, although it's still working, it's kind of annoying. What is the problem, and how I can fix it?

Comment: @ Ten Kho, are you are trying to install spyder using pip inside your environment. What does the error sign say .

Comment: just some pop-up error sign that kinda annoying, although the app still running well. the error text is above ("The proceduce entry point ? ...")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm having the same issue, and I've tested all new installations via pip that will encounter this issue. It seems the problem is related to creating the virtual environment on Windows OS.

As Ten Kho posted, the only error message is a pop-out window that says entry point error.

I fixed the problem by install scoop (guide can be found here https://scoop.sh/), and use scoop to reinstall python on windows. This fixed the pythoncom38.dll issue for me.